# Session Management in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session-management

I am new in MVC. I am creating new WebApplication in MVC4 Razor. I want to maintain User Login session for all pages. Can any one Explain me how to maintain session for all views in MVC with small example.

Comment: Do you want to show user login on all the pages?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Session management is simple. Session object is available inside MVC controller and in `HttpContext.Current.Session`. It is the same object. Here is a basic example of how to use Session:

### Write

```
Session["Key"] = new User("Login"); //Save session value
```

### Read

```
user = Session["Key"] as User; //Get value from session
```

### Answering your question

```
if (Session["Key"] == null){
   RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

Check out [Forms Authentication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-27splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF) to implement highly secure authentication model.

---

UPDATE: For newer versions of ASP.NET MVC you should use ASP.NET Identity Framework. Please check out [this article](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity).

Comment: how do i check that session for every views. if session not exist then how to redirect to login form.

Comment: @SanketS: Look in to SimpleMembership, it will do all this for you (and offer the convenience of using the `[Authorize]` attribute).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Example.
Say we want to manage session after checking user validation,
so for this demo only I am hard coding checking valid user.
On account Login

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            if(model.UserName=="xyz" && model.Password=="xyz")
            {
                Session["uname"] = model.UserName;
                Session.Timeout = 10;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
}
```

On Index Page

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if(Session["uname"]==null)
            {
                return Redirect("~/Account/Login");
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Welcome " + Session["uname"]);
            }
        }
```

On SignOut Button

```
Session.Remove("uname");
return Redirect("~/Account/Login");
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you worked on Asp.Net application?
Using Forms Authentication you can easily maintain user session.

Find the below given links for your reference:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-27splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Set Session

```
public IActionResult SetState()
{
    // State Save on 
    string name = "ITI";
    int age = 23;
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("StudentName", name);
    HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("StudentAge", age);

    return Content("Data Saved");
}
```

Get Session

```
public IActionResult GetState()
{
    string Name = "NULL";
    int Age = 0;
    if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("StudentName") != null)
    {
        Name = HttpContext.Session.GetString("StudentName");
        Age = (int)HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("StudentAge");
        return Content($"Get Data Success, Name = {Name} \t Age = {Age}");
    }
    return Content($"Get Data Not Success, Name = {Name} \t Age = {Age}");
}
```