# How do i Maintain Session in C# MVC Partial Views which will access in different Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am Trying to Design a web App using MVC .. i am trying to access user Login information throughout the application until the user Logout from the application.

please anyone help me...
it's most helpful for me if we add session in list variable and pass throughout the application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session Management in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181085/session-management-in-mvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach to do this is not through session, just use the claims, and it will store the data in session cookies:
So you have to add claims at

> IdentityModels class

then you have to write the claims in

> GenerateUserIdentityAsync method

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            var userId = userIdentity.GetUserId();
            var role = manager.GetRoles(userId);

            // Add custom user claims here
            userIdentity.AddClaims(new[] {
                new Claim("Your claim name", Value that you want to store it)
                });
            return userIdentity;
        }
```

Then you have to create a new class

```
public static class IdentityExtensions
    {
        public static Guid GetMyClaim(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("Your claim name");
            return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
        }
}
```

After this you can access it like this

```
User.Identity.GetMyClaim
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio will do most of the leg work for you on this front, just spin up a new MVC app and add authentication.  The asp membership can save you a lot of time here.

To point you in the right direction
New Project -> Add New Project Window -> Visual C# -> Web -> Asp .net Application -> MVC